# what affects Admob ad impression and click

Tags: android, admob, google-ads-api

I have two apps, both have one bottom ad banner, on admob platform it shows the `impression` number is similiar, but the `click` number varies much. 
I want to know which factor affects the number of click? Why two ads has similar impressions but varies in click number?

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's just an ad that people happen to bee more interested in, so they click through it more frequently?

Answer (score 0):

Better ad placements and more relatable ads typically get more clicks. Also if you refresh your ads more frequently your impression/click ratio falls.

If you are getting way more clicks that seem suspicious you can [report it](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3342054?hl=en).

Comment: my two app are similar, and the positions of the ads are the same.

Comment: I think I found the reason, it's about the ad type. It seems text ads are better, and get more clicks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check the other parameters of your report inside Admob admin panel.
Check region, time of impressions, language and the other parameters.
Futhermore, I you want, you can post here your screenshots.

Comment: How to measure/check region, time of impressions, language in report ? Only Date option is available. There is no time option in reports.